# Mysterious gap appearing under full-screen element when overlayed div is scrolled all the way down (but only in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I have a full-screen Leaflet map that should always take up 100% of the page

When my bootstrap jumbotron (an absolute positioned div) is scrolled all the way down, a gap appears below the map, which disappears only if the jumbotron is scrolled all the way up.

It only seems to be happening in Chrome / Brave, not in Mozilla or Safari.

How can I fix this and what is going on?

This is normal

[image]

This is the gap

[image]

```
html, body, #map (#map is the map)
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
/* === Jumbotron Displaying Music (when scrolled, problem occurs === */

#active-music-jumbo
{
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  min-width:480px;
}
#active-music-jumbo *
{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1002;
}
#active-music-jumbo
{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  z-index:1000;
  position:absolute;
  float: both;
  clear:none;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-height: calc(100% - 20px);
  display:none;
  max-width: 480px;
}
```

To reproduce, you may visit the live site [here](https://music.cxc.world)

Comment: Can't reproduce on `Chrome 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: @ZohirSalak I just checked with Chrome `Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Mac `10.14.4` and it is 100% happening for me. 

Make sure you scroll down with some force on the jumbotron. You must click one of the circles to get the jumbotron to appear

Comment: @ZohirSalak here is a screenshot showing what I am saying: https://www.dropbox.com/s/azkm84xm1j3bwd0/Screenshot%202020-05-13%2009.07.48.png?dl=0

Comment: I see it, the `.jumbotron` has `margin-bottom: 2rem;` remove it

Comment: @ZohirSalak that was it! Thanks so much! If you would like credit, you can just send that as an answer and I will mark it correct!